# Why function in Js don`t return false to form

Tags: javascript, html

I create a calculator in js. I wanted to use form and submit button, but despite the fact that it is entered to return false, it still goes as true and wants to go to a non-existent page in php.

validation is also added but I don't know what is causing the problem

````
<html>
<body>
    <center>
    <form name="formularz" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return sprawdzForm()" method="post">
        A: <input type="number" name="a">
        <select id="Wybieracz">
            <option value="+">Dodawanie</option>
            <option value="-">Odejmowanie</option>
            <option value="*">Mnożenie</option>
            <option value="/">Dzielenie</option>
        </select>
        B: <input type="number" name="b">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>    
    <span id="par1"></span>

    <script>
    

        function sprawdzForm() {
            var wynik = 0;
            var x = document.forms["formularz"]["a"].value;
            x = parseInt(x);
            var y = document.forms["formularz"]["b"].value;
            y = parseInt(y);
            var znaczek = document.forms["formularz"]["Wybieracz"].value;
            var txt = document.getElementById(par1);



            if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
                par1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                par1.innerHTML = "Podaj liczbę";
            }    
            if(a == "" || b == "") {
                par1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                par1.innerHTML = "a lub b jest puste";
            } 

            switch(znaczek){
                case "+":
                    wynik = x+y;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    wynik = x-y;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    wynik = x*y
                    break;
                case "/": 
                    wynik = x/y; 
                    break;
            }

            par1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            par1.innerHTML = "Twój wynik to : " + wynik;
            return false;
        }            
    </script>
    </center>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line: `var txt = document.getElementById(par1);` you are setting the variable `txt` to an element found with id "par1". So first you have to put par1 in quotes:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("par1");
```

After that, all your references to that element use a non-existent variable `par1` ... replace that with `txt` and things will be better. Can't comment on the php part, looks like it should work, theoretically.

Comment: ok so i did this (replaced "par1" with "txt") and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails..

```
a is undefined
```

But this code working, you can try this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form
      name="formularz"
      action="/action_page.php"
      onsubmit="sprawdzForm(); return false"
      method="post"
    >
      A: <input type="number" name="a" />
      <select id="Wybieracz">
        <option value="+">Dodawanie</option>
        <option value="-">Odejmowanie</option>
        <option value="*">Mnożenie</option>
        <option value="/">Dzielenie</option>
      </select>
      B: <input type="number" name="b" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <span id="par1"></span>

    <script>
      function sprawdzForm() {
        console.log("function working");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a workaround.
create your form like that

```
<form onsubmit="sprawdzForm(event)"  name="formularz" action="/action_page.php" method="post">

<!--add your from elements -->

 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

then in your javascript function, prevent the default behaviour of the `form` then submit it whenever you want

```
function sprawdzForm(e) {
  //prevent default behaviour of the form
  e.preventDefault()

  /*Do some code here forexaple validation*/

  //submit the form
  e.target.submit()

}
```